# How to read and convert this json into a DF?

Tags: python, json, parsing, nested

I want to convert this nested json into a df.
Tried different functions but none works correctly.

The encoding that worked for my was -
encoding = "utf-8-sig"

```
[{'replayableActionOperationState': 'SKIPPED',
  'replayableActionOperationGuid': 'RAO_1037351',
  'failedMessage': 'Cannot replay action: RAO_1037351: com.ebay.sd.catedor.core.model.DTOEntityPropertyChange; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7777212484705611612, local class serialVersionUID = -1785129380151507142',
  'userMessage': 'Skip all mode',
  'username': 'gfannon',
  'sourceAuditData': [{'guid': '24696601-b73e-43e4-bce9-28bc741ac117',
    'operationName': 'UPDATE_CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE_PROPERTY',
    'creationTimestamp': 1563439725240,
    'auditCanvasInfo': {'id': '165059', 'name': '165059'},
    'auditUserInfo': {'id': 1, 'name': 'gfannon'},
    'externalId': None,
    'comment': None,
    'transactionId': '0f135909-66a7-46b1-98f6-baf1608ffd6a',
    'data': {'entity': {'guid': 'CA_2511202',
      'tagType': 'BOTH',
      'description': None,
      'name': 'Number of Shelves'},
     'propertyChanges': [{'propertyName': 'EntityProperty',
       'oldEntity': {'guid': 'CAP_35',
        'name': 'DisableAsVariant',
        'group': None,
        'action': 'SET',
        'value': 'true',
        'tagType': 'SELLER'},
       'newEntity': {'guid': 'CAP_35',
        'name': 'DisableAsVariant',
        'group': None,
        'action': 'SET',
        'value': 'false',
        'tagType': 'SELLER'}}],
     'entityChanges': None,
     'primary': True}}],
  'targetAuditData': None,
  'conflictedGuids': None,
  'fatal': False}]
```

This is what i tried so far, there are more tries but that got me as close as i can.

```
with open(r"Desktop\Ann's json parsing\report.tsv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  
    df = json_normalize(data)
    print (df)

pd.DataFrame(df) ## The nested lists are shown as a whole column, im trying to parse those colums - 'failedMessage' and 'sourceAuditData'`I also tried json.loads/json(df) but the output isnt correct.

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a['sourceAuditData'][0]['data']['propertyChanges'][0]) ##This line will retrive one of the outputs i need but i dont know how to perform it on the whole file.
```

The expected result should be a csv/xlsx file with a column and value for each row.
[image: Desired output]

Comment: Before asking for any answers, kindly provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: what is a row in this example ? Why is `data`, `targetAuditData` etc. not in the output ? is it voluntary ?

Comment: Added the code i ran and what i have tried.

Comment: @Derlin data is one of the nested lists im trting to parse, so i need all the information in it to be shown as a separete colum in the outputfile.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example:

```
def unroll_dict(d):
    data = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            data.append((k, ''))
            data.extend(unroll_dict(v[0]))
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            data.append((k, ''))
            data.extend(unroll_dict(v))
        else: 
            data.append((k,v))
    return data
```

And given the data in your question is stored in the variable `example`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(unroll_dict(example[0])).set_index(0).transpose()
```